# How to rollback a single migration file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I only want to undo one migration file, something like

> rake db:rollback VERSION=$TIMESTAMP

This command doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=$TIMESTAMP` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

rake db:rollback is now the way.